# Any ways to hide j_spring_security_check

Tags: security, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security for my rest application. However, the default authentication url is j_spring_security_check which basically announces my security structure out in the open if an attacker was to check the request url. Is there any way to hide this url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `loginPage` property:

```
.formLogin() 
           .loginPage("/login") 
           .permitAll();
```

See docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/ section 3.3. Java Configuration and Form Login

Comment: Thank you. Forgive my weak attention. I have been reading loads of stuff. I missed that part. I didnt think it created a post entry point back then.